# Saved User object is Null sometimes but works perfect sometime in Windows phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I'm getting a problem in my Class function. I call a function and in that function i call another function to get saved user detail. I saved detail in user object to use further. But user object some time becomes null and some time return exact value during debugging ....

Here is my Class function..

```
   public async void Save_Data_in_Log(string EventName, string completeUrl)
    {

        Get_User_Detail_Event();
        //Above function is another function to get User detail in   savedUserObject. 

        UserId = savedUserObject.id;
        device_id_string = savedUserObject.deviceId;
        status = "System Event";
        device_type = "Windows";

        DateTime universalTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string universalformate = universalTime.ToString("yyyy MM dd, HH:mm:ss");

        string data_to_save_in_log_File = serial_No + " | " + universalformate + " | " + UserId + " | " + device_id_string + " | " + device_type + " | " + status + " | " + EventName + " | " + completeUrl;



    }


 private async void Get_User_Detail_Event()
    {
        if (settingsto_save_detail.LoadSetting("currentUser") != null)
        {
            savedUserObject = await settingsto_save_detail.RetrieveObjectAsync<UserDetail>("currentUser");
        }
    }
```

Why this function does not give exact User detail.? This works some time good but mostly give Null object.

Please guide me how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how the await-async asynchronisation thing works. The flow is not synchronous. 
change the return type to Task like this:

```
async Task Get_User_Detail_Event
```

and invoke the method like this:

```
await Get_User_Detail_Event();
```